# How to stop minicart remove confirm popup to close on body click in magento2

Tags: magento2

I want to stop minicart remove content popup to close when body click
[image]

Comment: please find below given solution, https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/281877/52244 hope this will solve your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve an output as per given request.

By adding an option value in confirm modal popup code **`clickableOverlay: false`**

now question is where to add this line of code.

So In theme, added a js file **sidebar.js** to `app\design\frontend\[NAMESPACE]\[THEME]\Magento_Checkout\web\js\sidebar.js` **if not exist** then copy form `vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\sidebar.js`

(assuming  **sidebar.js** file there in theme) then in this file,

find `events['click ' + this.options.button.remove]` approx line 88.

> this event will triggering on click of mini-cart delete item and
>   confirm popup will be  initialize, so add the option code `clickableOverlay: false`,

see example.

```
 events['click ' + this.options.button.remove] =  function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                confirm({
                    clickableOverlay: false, // to avoid close confirm popup on click of overlay
                    content: self.options.confirmMessage, ...
```

> **Theory :**  confirm popup extends form `$.mage.modal` and this jquery widget have a property  **clickableOverlay** and having default value is 
>   **true**. so make it **false** to **avoid confirm popup close on click of overlay** or in other words to avoid closing the confirm popup on click of body.

Hope this **code snippet** will help you to solve your concern.

**Note : This code is effect in `minicart delete item confirm popup only` and if need to achieve same for other place  then add same code to other popups as well or if need for global then override `$.mage.modal widget` as explain logic change can be done via mixin too, the share code is just for reference only.**

Comment: But doing this my all popup will affected right? how can do it for perticular this popup?

Comment: @RutveeSojitra this is particular to **minicart delete item button event only**. that is the reason *we have to override this file or create a mixin* and override this particular function.

Comment: @RutveeSojitra please try and see, if it solve your concern please mark it as valid answer.

Comment: Perfect!!!! thank you

Comment: @RutveeSojitra Happy to here that, Got perfect matched solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just add/change this line, option set to `true` will close the popup and option set to `false` will keep the popup opened.

```
clickableOverlay: false
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add this code in your theme's folder.

Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/form.phtml

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/translate',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm',
    "mage/template",
], function ($, $t, confirm, mageTemplate) {
    $('.action-delete').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        confirm({
            title: $t("Remove item cart"),
            content: $t("Do you want remove this item of the cart?"),
            modalClass: "classModal",
            actions: {
                confirm: function () {
                    var params = $(e.currentTarget).data('post');
                    var formTemplate = '<form action="<%- data.action %>" method="post">'
                        + '<% _.each(data.data, function(value, index) { %>'
                        + '<input name="<%- index %>" value="<%- value %>">'
                        + '<% }) %></form>';

                    var formKeyInputSelector = 'input[name="form_key"]';

                    var formKey = $(formKeyInputSelector).val();
                    if (formKey) {
                        params.data.form_key = formKey;
                    }
                    $(mageTemplate(formTemplate, {
                        data: params
                    })).appendTo('body').hide().submit();
                }
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: i want to just stop to close the popup on body click event rest is magento already doing

Comment: Ok but by default magento if outside poup click already close it so may be some mistake in your side

Comment: "if outside poup click already close".. yes excatly... that's why i want to stop it

Answer (score 0):

We fixed this issue in a custom theme using a RequireJS mixin by adding the following files:

```
app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Ui/web/js/model/modal-mixin.js

define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper'
], function ($, wrapper) {
    'use strict';

    return function (modal) {

        modal.prototype.openModal = wrapper.wrap(modal.prototype.openModal, function(original) {

            var result = original();
            $('.' + this.options.overlayClass).appendTo('.modal-popup._show');
            //Setting z-index of inner-wrap to 900 so that it is actually clickable and not hiding behind the overlay
            $('.modal-inner-wrap').css('z-index', 900);
            return result;
        });

        return modal;
    };
});

app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/requirejs-config.js

var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal': {
                'Magento_Ui/js/model/modal-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**Please check with above code, its for reference code for how to disable / enable anywhere click in body to popup stable.**

I hope its work for you.

Comment: how to decide here that all popup will effected by it?

Comment: check with .modal-popup  with popup will effected.